# What could the Department of Temporal Investigations do in the event of a time paradox?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the famous DS9 episode *Trials and Tribble-ations* we see the Department of Temporal Investigations asks some questions of Sisko and his recent unexpected time travel.  What would they do in the event that a paradox was created, unless they had time travel abilities which, as far as is known through the series, is not yet discovered and used until about the 26th century (*A Matter of Time* - TNG), suggesting they come from the future and could create a paradox themselves!

Comment: In the Trek series traveling through time is actually rather easy, Spock makes the calculations a bunch of times.  Seems all you need to do is sling-shot your way around the sun.  He even does it in Star Trek IV - The Voyage Home (the one with the Whales) and he had just been resurrected only a three months ago.  There's also the Guardian of Forever, as seen in TOS "The City on the Edge of Forever" & TAS "Yesteryear".  Heck for all we know they still have a time sphere from the Trek / Legion of Super-Heroes crossover =P

Comment: As Lucsly and Dulmur, from Temporal Investigations, imply it could be rather difficult to identify a change in the timeline.

Comment: I'm not sure it was actually their job to do anything, apart from reporting on whether or not the people involved had broken the rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several episodes of *TOS*, notably *Assignment: Earth*, that show the ability of Star Fleet to travel back in time at will during the 23rd century. One would assume that 24th century technology makes this even easier. So while it might be difficult for the Department of Temporal Investigations to deal with a time paradox if said paradox wiped them out or went unnoticed, in the event of a well-documented episode like *Trials and Tribble-ations* or *Assignment: Earth*, they'd have the option of going back and fixing things.

Comment: Damn, that was quick. Accepted in less than a minute.